# Find when $\frac{3^n+6^n+9^n}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}$ is an integer

Tags: number-theory

> Find all natural numbers $n$ such that $$\dfrac{3^n+6^n+9^n}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}$$ is an integer.

For $n = 1$ we have $\dfrac{18}{3} = 6$.

For $n = 2$ we have $\dfrac{126}{18} = 7$.

For $n = 3$ we have $\dfrac{972}{126} = \dfrac{54}{7}$

For $n = 4$ we have $\dfrac{7938}{972} = \dfrac{49}{6}$.

I don't seem to find any other integers for the fraction for $n > 2$. How can we find all of the $n$ such that it is an integer?

Comment: Your number converges to somewhere when $n$ gets larger. Maybe you can use it to prove that number is not integer for large enough $n$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**
$$\dfrac{3^n+6^n+9^n}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}=3 \dfrac{1+2^n+3^n}{1+2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}}$$

**Hint 2:** If $n \geq 2$ then

$$2 < \dfrac{1+2^n+3^n}{1+2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}}<3$$

So you need to solve
$$\dfrac{1+2^n+3^n}{1+2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}}=\frac{7}{3}  \mbox{ and }\\
\dfrac{1+2^n+3^n}{1+2^{n-1}+3^{n-1}}=\frac{8}{3}$$

Comment: Simpler than mine.

Comment: Can the downvoter explain?

Answer (score 2):

$\begin{array}\\
\dfrac{3^n+6^n+9^n}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}
&=\dfrac{3^n+6^n+9^n}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}-9+9\\
&=\dfrac{3^n+6^n+9^n-9(3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1})}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}+9\\
&=\dfrac{3^n+6^n+9^n-9\cdot 3^{n-1}-9\cdot 6^{n-1}-9^{n}}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}+9\\
&=\dfrac{3^n+6^n-9\cdot 3^{n-1}-9\cdot 6^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}+9\\
&=\dfrac{3^n+6^n- 3^{n+1}-\frac23  6^{n}}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}+9\\
&=\dfrac{\frac13 6^n-2\cdot 3^{n}}{3^{n-1}+6^{n-1}+9^{n-1}}+9\\
&=\dfrac{3\cdot (2/3)^{n-1}-9\cdot (1/3)^{n-1}}{(1/3)^{n-1}+(2/3)^{n-1}+1}+9\\
\end{array}
$

For
$n \ge 3$,
$0 \lt 3\cdot (2/3)^{n-1}-9\cdot (1/3)^{n-1}
\lt 1$,
so this is never an integer
for $n \ge 2$.

Comment: I am not sure, bit I think that your proof can be simplified quite a bit. I think that the sequence is increasing and convergent to 9, so after passing 8 is not an integer anymore.

Comment: Probably true. I just charge ahead until I get an answer I like.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: It looks like considering the top and bottom $\mod 4$ narrows it down quite a bit.